# How to specify a “Last-Modified” header in PHP

Tags: php, http, last-modified

I am building a website that uses PHP, and would like to know how to send a `Last-Modifed` header that reflects the actual date that my files were last modified. As I'm sure you know, PHP strips away the `Last-Modified` header by default, meaning that the  page is always considered fresh.

In order to take advantage of caching, I wish to apply PHP to manually send a `Last-Modified` header to reflect when the  containing PHP file was last edited.

I have looked on the web and have found no satisfactory examples. Any code examples of how to achieve this would be gratefully appreciated.

(Please accept my apologies in advance if this sounds like bit a novice question.)

Comment: _"In order to take advantage of caching"_ - be aware, that you will not only have to _send_ that header, but you will also need to handle requests made with an `If-Modified-Since` header accordingly then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I'm sure you know, PHP strips away the Last-Modified header by default

Nope.

```bash
$ cat test.php
<?php
\header('Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT');

$ php -S 127.0.0.1:6969 test.php
[Fri Apr 14 00:25:18 2023] PHP 8.1.17 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:6969) started
```

and then

```bash
$ curl -v http://localhost:6969/1.php

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:6969...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 6969 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:6969
> User-Agent: curl/7.85.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Host: localhost:6969
< Date: Thu, 13 Apr 2023 22:24:10 GMT
< Connection: close
< X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.17
< Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT
< Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

It gets returned as expected:

```bash
< Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT
```

**EDIT** To get the real modification date use [filemtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php):

```php
$modified = \date("F d Y H:i:s.", \filemtime($filename));
\header("Last-Modified: {$modified}");
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I am looking for is  way to send the `Last-Modified` date as a raw HTTP header, which relfects the date/time the actual PHP file was last updated.

Comment: `filemtime()` to the rescue. see edit

Comment: @JordanClark — It's pretty rare for it to be at all useful to use PHP if the last-modified time is determined solely by the time that PHP file was modified.

Comment: _"Nope."_ - I think what was meant was that PHP does not _send_ one by default, as requesting a _static_ file directly via the web server usually would.

Comment: But filtering out and not sending are completely different things. Also   if you think about why would you do that (not send it)for a while, then it should be immediate cleat PHP is unable to determine that by itself because it does not know what your code is doing. You might be static content but also completely random each time. And the script itself was last time modified in 2019. What would be your `last-modified` value if you not know the script logic and purpose? If you want that header, you must deal with it yourself for that very reason.